# Undefined method `allow_value'

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rspec-rails

Having a problem with  gem 'shoulda-matchers' on gem 'rails', '4.1.0.rc2', When i run my test i get an error

```
/Volumes/Khaya/myapp/spec/models/account_spec.rb:13:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>': undefined method `allow_value' for RSpec::ExampleGroups::Account_2::Validations:Class (NoMethodError)
```

**My gemfile**

```
gem 'rails', '4.1.0.rc2'


group :development, :test do
  gem 'guard'
  gem 'guard-livereload'
  gem 'rspec', '~> 3.0.0.beta2'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.0.0.beta'
  gem 'guard-rspec', require: false
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
  gem 'database_cleaner'
  gem 'minitest'
  gem 'shoulda-matchers'
end

group :development do
  #gem 'spring'
  gem 'better_errors'
  gem 'binding_of_caller', :platforms=>[:mri_19, :mri_20, :rbx]
  gem 'quiet_assets'
end
```

My test

```
it {should allow_value('vezu').for(:name)}
```

I can't figure out how to fix this. Am i missing something on my configuration?

Answer (score 0):

My mistake i had something like this

```
it should_not allow_value('VEZU S').for(:name)
```

instead of

```
it {should_not allow_value('VEZU S').for(:name)}
```